# Docker compose npm install took hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, npm, docker-compose, nestjs

I am using aws ec2 free tier for Ubuntu 20.04. I am deploying nginx, Jenkins, Nest.js application using docker, but while building Nest.js, npm install glob rimraf took literally HOURS. Is it because of AWS free tier which is too small? When I monitored CPU usage from ec2 console, it is almost 100%. However, glob and rimraf is not a huge package. They are only 56kb and 70kb... but downloading images like node is really fast.
Is there any way to speed up this process?
[image]

Here is my dockerFile and docker-compose.yaml

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install glob rimraf
RUN npm install --only=development
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.9 as production
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

```
services:
    proxy:
        image: nginx:latest # 최신 버전의 Nginx 사용
        container_name: proxy # container 이름은 proxy
        ports:
            - '80:80' # 80번 포트를 host와 container 맵핑
        networks:
            - nestjs-network
        volumes:
            - ./proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf # nginx 설정 파일 volume 맵핑
        restart: 'unless-stopped' # 내부에서 에러로 인해 container가 죽을 경우 restart
    dev:
        container_name: nestjs_api_dev
        image: nestjs-api-dev:1.0.0
        build:
            context: .
            target: development
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        command: node dist/main
        # ports:
        #     - 3000:3000
        expose:
            - '3000' # 다른 컨테이너에게 3000번 포트 open
        networks:
            - nestjs-network
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        restart: unless-stopped
    prod:
        container_name: nestjs_api_prod
        image: nestjs-api-prod:1.0.0
        build:
            context: .
            target: production
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        command: npm run start:prod
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
            - 9229:9229
        networks:
            - nestjs-network
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        restart: unless-stopped
    jenkins:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./jenkins/Dockerfile
        image: jenkins/jenkins
        restart: always
        container_name: jenkins
        user: root
        environment:
            - JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        expose:
            - '8080'
        networks:
            - nestjs-network
        volumes:
            - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        environment:
            TZ: 'Asia/Seoul'
networks:
    nestjs-network:
```

Comment: Was the instance out of CPU credits?

Comment: @MarkB I do not know much about cpu credits, but it uses 5 cpu credits now, which is a maximum.

Comment: @yongseunglee how does it work on your computer?

Comment: @DoryNguyen I am using macbook Air 2019, and it took only a minute...

Comment: "I do not know much about cpu credits" You need to read up on how CPU credits work on AWS if you are going to continue using EC2 instances that require CPU credits. You need to check if the server was down to 0 CPU credits left, at which point the CPU will be extremely throttled and you will see slowness issues like this.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks I will read it.